# CSS modify only H2 tag above P tag

Tags: html, css

See the code below, I need to chnage the font-size of H2 tag within the second 'content-block', I can not modify the Div Tag or the h2 tag themselves directly, I can only modify the content below the h2 tags.

```
<div class="content-block">
<h2>Title here</h2>
<p>this is some text.</p>
</div>

<div class="content-block">
<h2>Modify This title only</h2>
<p>this is some more text.</p>
<style>## I can add CSS here ##</style>
</div>
```

Edit: I can not be sure how many 'content-block' divs will be above the one I want to modify, it chnages from page to page. (A shopping cart)

How is the possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.content-block + .content-block h2 {/* your css */}
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/4013393

`+` is what we call [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: Hmm, this does work. however I can not be sure of the number of 'content-block's above the one I want to modify, it changes from time to time. Depending on the page.

Comment: Well, how do you determine which is the one you want to change though?

Comment: @Ezra you have to have a pattern which will be the same in any case to be able to select the requirement element. Will it have a specific position from bottom or top? Will it have specific content?

Comment: @Sotiris, the content of the H2 tag I want to modify should stay the same on each page.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, All i can do is add the CSS just below the one I want to change. When a company changes an hour minimum to change a single CSS character, you look for other ways to do it.

Comment: @Ezra there is no way to select it using CSS having only the content of the element as a pattern. You can do it only with javascript.

Comment: @Ezra: That's not changing a single CSS character. That probably means either a hack, or a structure change. I would suggest you think hard and well about whether your content structure is correct, and whether or not further classnames/etc needs to be added.

Comment: @Sotiris, I thought as much. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, well true. A class would need to be added, but I have no control over that. :( Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 :nth-child() Selector hope it may solve your problem

check the Example Here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp